# Checking if a value is in a list based on indexes

Tags: python

If I have a list that is made up of indexes from a list of lists, how would I use an index collected from a value in that list and find out which list it is in?

Here is an example:

```
listolists = [
    [0, 8, 4, 0, 7],
    [3, 6, 0, 9, 0],
    [4, 0, 3, 7, 0],
    [7, 0, 7, 0, 6]
    ]
section1 = [listolists[0][0], listolists[0][1], listolists[1][0], listolists[1][1]]
section2 = [listolists[3][4], listolists[2][4], listolists[3][3], listolists[2][3]]
for c row in enumerate(listolists):
    if 0 in row:
        *if 1, 2, and 3 are in whichever "section"(section1 or section2) the 0 is in*
            print ("Success")
```

The goal of this would be for the program to look at the index of the 0 that it has found. Then it should see if the 0's index matches up with any of the "sections." Then it should look in the section that the 0 is in and check if that list contains 1, 2, or 3. The part with the * around it is obviously incorrect and is the part that I need to find the correct syntax on. I have looked all over the internet and have been unable to find any help for this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to clarify what the pseudo-expression "1, 2, 3, in whatever section the 0 is in" means, with examples. I suggest that you use a short name like `table` to avoid the extremely annoying SO horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: You're also missing at least 4 commas.

Comment: "an index collected from a vale in that list" Could you explain this better ? What a "vale" is ?

Comment: Sorry I think I have fixed most of your problems with it. An error occurred with Stack Overflow while I was trying to post this and I didn't realize that some of the errors I fixed didn't actually post when it started working again. It also wasn't complete at the end there. Does it make sense now though?

Comment: @joaquin: Levenshtein suggests "value"

Comment: It has now been changed to value. Sorry about that.

Comment: Wow looked up levenshtein...very interesting. How did you do that?

Comment: @chingchong: Explain coherently what you want, WITH EXAMPLE OUTPUT and the syntax should then be readily apparent.

Comment: @chingchong: mental_approximate_matching_search("vale", question_title)

Comment: I did some edits. There will be no output. I hope this explains it enough for you to understand my goal.

Comment: @chingchong: No output? In that case you can achieve the same effect by replacing ALL your code by a single empty line.

Comment: No visible output would be noted to the user. Obviously I don't want an empty line. No need to be like that.

Comment: Do my edits tell you what you need to know? I don't know how to clarify much further.

Comment: There. Now the user would see "Success" if it works.

Comment: Printing "Success" if it works does NOT clarify what the condition is! See the answer I am about to post.

Comment: What "condition" is not clarified? Still waiting for an answer....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6318/discussion-between-chingchong-and-john-machin)

Comment: @chingchong: Extremely sorry to keep you waiting while I attended to other matters, but your support contract doesn't include immediate response.

Comment: Yes I know. Sorry to be so impatient.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed up some typoes, avoided the scroll bar, shown the contents of `section` and `section2`, and added a print statement:

```
table = [
    [0, 8, 4, 0, 7],
    [3, 6, 0, 9, 0],
    [4, 0, 3, 7, 0],
    [7, 0, 7, 0, 6]
    ]
section1 = [table[0][0], table[0][1], table[1][0], table[1][1]]
print "section1:", section1
section2 = [table[3][4], table[2][4], table[3][3], table[2][3]]
print "section2:", section2

def mystery(query_value, sections, some_integers_whose_purport_is_unknown):
    return "Not a clue"

qv = 0    
for row_index, row in enumerate(table):
    if qv in row:
        # if 1, 2, and 3 are in X
        # where X = whichever "section"(section1 or section2) the 0 is in
        a_boolean = mystery(qv, (section1, section2), (1, 2, 3))
        print "row_index: %r, condition_value: %r" % (row_index, a_boolean)
```

Output:

```
section1: [0, 8, 3, 6]
section2: [6, 0, 0, 7]
row_index: 0, condition_value: 'Not a clue'
row_index: 1, condition_value: 'Not a clue'
row_index: 2, condition_value: 'Not a clue'
row_index: 3, condition_value: 'Not a clue'
```

You need to explain what those condition_values are, and how they are derived. Including:

(1) what `X = whichever "section"(section1 or section2) the 0 is in` means ... noting that `0` appears in BOTH `section1` and `section2`

(2) what `1, 2, and 3 are in X` means: perhaps `1 in X and 2 in X and 3 in X`, but that would be `False` for all cases (no 1, no 2, only one 3 in either of the sections).

Comment: (1) What it means is that if 0 is in a section (Whether it is in both or not) Then it will do whatever. i.e. print ("whatever")

Comment: (2) This part doesn't really matter. But what it is supposed to do is show how I would then use whatever "section" I found with the other part where I find the section containing the 0. All of the numbers use in this were just examples so it really doesn't matter if they are in it or not, just that it checks to see if they are and it looks in the correct place. It should make sure they are all in the list.

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for with those condition values. Perhaps further explanation of what you need more information about? Not in Python code?

Comment: [John Machin. Mission:Impossible. Ghost Protocol. Now playing](http://www.missionimpossible.com/)

Comment: @JohnMachin Please clarify your question and I would be happy to help.

Comment: Please answer me. Instead of chatting about Mission Impossible Ghost Protocol. Thank You.